# WP Plugin to write inputs to stylesheet

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Im a bit new to this side of Wordpress and wanted to get some help with the best way to go about this. I created a plugin and what i want it to do is have a simple form with a few fields that will write information to a stylesheet. In this case i have a admin.css file that i enqueued in my themes functions.php file and it works for style changes but it would be easier to have a menu in the backend that will write some info to that file.
how would i go about this and which is the best method?

Answer (score 0):

well this will be done with fwrite function that i think more complex. try to add in simply  tags and add_action in to wp_head directoly